# How to call static block into graphql query in alpine js framework

Tags: magento2, blocks, static-block, graphql, alpine.js

```
enter code <div class="bg-container border-t border-b border-container">
    <div class="container px-5 py-6 mx-auto flex items-center sm:flex-row flex-col"
        x-data="cmsblock()"
        x-init="fetch('http://127.0.0.1:96/magento2test/graphql')
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data =>cmsBlock = data.cmsBlock)
        "
    >
        <span class="ml-3 text-xl"
        x-data="'&quot;{cmsBlock}&quot;'"
        >
         <script>
           
            function cmsBlock(){
                cmsBlock{
                    cmsBlocks(identifiers: "footer_links") {
                        items {
                          identifier
                          title
                          content
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
        </span>
        
    </div>
</div>
 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain what your issue is, do you have any errors?

Comment: yes sure . this error is display : Uncaught ReferenceError: cmsblock is not defined

Comment: I am using this code in phtml file but as in console.log i am getting this error.

Comment: There are several issues with this, I advise you study Alpine JS and compare what you have done with hyva-themes/magento2-default-theme/Magento_Theme/templates/elements/slider.phtml

If I get time I'll go through it later.

Comment: Hi Mehul. By the looks of that code snippet, you might be trying to get this to work in Hyvä Themes. I'd like to point out that we have excellent support for these kind of questions on our Slack. You should have access to that if you're working with a valid license for Hyvä. If you're working on behalf of a merchant that purchased a license, please ask them to request access to support, we'll be happy to help you with this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass right string/identifiers: ["footer_links_block"]

{
cmsBlocks(identifiers: ["footer_links_block"]) {
items {
content
identifier
title
}
}
}
Response
{
"data": {
"cmsBlocks": {
"items": [
{
"content": "<ul class="footer links">\n    <li class="nav item"><a href="http://magento.local/index.php/about-us/">About us\n    <li class="nav item"><a href="http://magento.local/index.php/customer-service/">Customer Service\n\n",
"identifier": "footer_links_block",
"title": "Footer Links Block"
}
]
}
}
}

this will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you like this post please like and [follow my blog](https://php-scripts-form.blogspot.com/2023/06/to-call-static-block-into-graphql-query.html).
To call a static block into a GraphQL query in the Alpine.js framework within Magento 2, you would need to follow these steps:

Create a GraphQL query:

Define your query in the app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/etc/graphql/schema.graphqls file. For example:

graphql
Copy code

```
type Query {
  staticBlock(identifier: String!): String @resolver(class: "{Vendor}\\{Module}\\Model\\Resolver\\StaticBlock") @doc(description: "Retrieve the content of a static block by identifier")
}
```

Create a Resolver class:

Create the resolver class app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/Model/Resolver/StaticBlock.php. In this class, you will define the logic to retrieve the static block content. Here's an example implementation:

php
Copy code

```
<?php

namespace {Vendor}\{Module}\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Cms\Model\BlockRepository;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\Resolver\ContextInterface;

class StaticBlock implements ResolverInterface
{
    private $blockRepository;

    public function __construct(BlockRepository $blockRepository)
    {
        $this->blockRepository = $blockRepository;
    }

    public function resolve(
        ContextInterface $context,
        array $args,
        array $directives = [],
        \GraphQL\Type\Definition\ResolveInfo $info = null
    ) {
        $identifier = $args['identifier'];

        try {
            $block = $this->blockRepository->getByIdentifier($identifier);
            return $block->getContent();
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Utilize the GraphQL query in Alpine.js:

In your Alpine.js component, make an HTTP request to the GraphQL endpoint to fetch the static block content. Here's an example using Axios:

javascript
Copy code

```
<template>
  <div x-data="{ blockContent: '' }">
    <div x-html="blockContent"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  mounted() {
    axios.post('/graphql', {
      query: `
        query {
          staticBlock(identifier: "your_block_identifier") 
        }
      `,
    })
      .then(response => {
        this.blockContent = response.data.data.staticBlock;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  },
}
</script>
```

Ensure to replace {Vendor} and {Module} with your actual vendor and module names, respectively. Also, replace "your_block_identifier" with the identifier of the static block you want to retrieve.

Remember to adjust the code according to your specific requirements and ensure that you have appropriate permissions and configurations set up for GraphQL and the Alpine.js framework in your Magento 2 installation.